# Android how to show the button over the imageview in android

Tags: android, image

I want to show the button over the image in image view. Can any one have any idea how to do this. I'm new in android programming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using this u can create the button on the Bitmap dynamically...

```
public class MainAct extends GrapActivity implements OnClickListener {


private Button saveButton;
private Button clearButton;

// onCreate Activity
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          

 // content view 
signature = new MyView(this); 

// Dynamically created button on bitmap & canvas

RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);        
myLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 

// For Save Button
saveButton = new Button(this); 
saveButton.setText("Save"); 
saveButton.setOnClickListener(this); 

// For Clear Button
clearButton = new Button(this); 
clearButton.setText("Clear"); 
clearButton.setOnClickListener(this); 

myLayout.addView(signature); 
myLayout.addView(saveButton); 
myLayout.addView(clearButton); 

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
//Alignments
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); 
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); 
saveButton.setLayoutParams(params); 

//Alignments
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT); 
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); 
clearButton.setLayoutParams(params2); 

saveButton.bringToFront(); 
clearButton.bringToFront(); 
this.setContentView(myLayout); 
new Thread(new RefreshRunner()).start(); 

 // onclick listner for CLEAR button
 clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Activity for Clearing the Screen
        startActivity(new Intent(ThisAct.this, ThisAct.class));
        finish();
    }
});

// onclick listner for SAVE button
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //capture the image  
            try {                    
                saveAsJpg(mBitmap);     
                startActivity(new Intent(ThisAct.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            } catch (IOException e) {                   
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }  
    });     
 } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a layout container such as `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` to contain the `Button` and `ImageView` and give them appropriate attributes so that they overlap as desired.